Computing the multiple-integral of a $n$ variable symmetric function
I'm interested in evaluating the following integral analytically, numerically, or using a combination of both. Let
$$ I_n(\rho) = 2^n\int_{\mathbb{R}_+^n} \sqrt{1+ \rho^2 \left(\prod_{k=1}^n x_k^{-2}\right) \left(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^{-2}\right)  } \exp\!\left( -\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2 - \rho^2\prod_{k=1}^n x_k^{-2} \right) \mathrm{d}x, \qquad \rho>0. $$
The term $2^n$ is there, so we have "nicer" numbers. Using the $\texttt{NIntegrate}$ function with $\texttt{PrecisionGoal -> 4}$ from Mathematica, I got the following sequence for $\rho=1$.



$n$
$I_n(1)$




$1$
$0.354524$


$2$
$0.328121$


$3$
$0.298973$


$4$
$0.270138$


$5$
$0.242674$


$6$
$0.216402$


$7$
$0.192150$


$8$
$0.172242$


$9$
$0.158585$


$10$
$0.074156$



I think that for $n>5$, this is not accurate, and I'm pretty sure that for $n=10$, it is far from the true value. If someone could shed light on some paths I could traverse, it would be much appreciated.
